# Constructor <ClassAdapter> in class <ClassAdapter> cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java

I'm looking to implement a `searchview` next to `recyclerview` to make filtering of book records occur. I'm having trouble on the following line in the `ListBooks.java` file:

- Line:

```
recyclerAdapter = new BookAdapter();
```

The error of this line is:

**error: constructor `BookAdapter` in class `BookAdapter` cannot be applied to given types; required: `List<Book>`,Context found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length**.

- `ListBooks.java`

```
public class ListBooks extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    BookAdapter recyclerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listar_livros);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerAdapter = new BookAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        DB db = new DB(this);
        List<Book> books = db.ReadBooks();
        
        if (books.size() > 0){
            BookAdapter bookadapter = new BookAdapter(books,ListBooks.this);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(bookadapter);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No books in database.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    
      @Override
      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
          getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_book,menu);
          MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.s_book);
          SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
          searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
              @Override
              public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                  return false;
              }
              @Override
              public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                  recyclerAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                  return false;
              }
          });
          return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
      }
}
```

- `BookAdapter.java`

```
public class BookAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BookAdapter.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    List<Book> books;
    List<Book> books2;
    Context context;
    DB db;

    public BookAdapter(List<Book> books, Context context) {
        this.books = books;
        this.books2 = new ArrayList<>(books2);
        this.context = context;
        bd = new BD(context);
    }
    
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return filter;
    }
    
    Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            List<Book> filter_books = new ArrayList<>();
            if (charSequence.toString().isEmpty()){
                filter_books.addAll(books2);
            } else {
                for (Book book: books2){
                    if (book.getTitle_book().toLowerCase().contains(charSequence.toString().toLowerCase())){
                        filter_book.add(book);
                    }
                }
            }
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = filter_books;
            return filterResults;
        }
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults filterResults) {
            books.clear();
            books.addAll((Collection<? extends Book>) filterResults.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: you aren't passing parameters, and you only have a constructor that takes parameters, what did you expect was going to happen?

Comment: I don't know the parameters that must be passed in the constructor, obviously nothing will happen.

Comment: "nothing will happen"? I wouldn't consider compile time errors 'nothing'. This is your code/application, you think we know better than you what you need to pass?

Comment: @Stultuske I really don't know what to pass in this constructor, I tried to pass the parameters that I found most suitable, but the compiler always points the error to the same line, or when it doesn't point to any error, the application stops working in the tests.

Comment: then maybe you should show that code, along with the actual error messages

Comment: I will compile and describe the error in my question.

Comment: @Stultuske question updated!

Comment: Could you maybe set the android tag, @Bolacer? This may aid in finding an answer. The code requires prior knowledge of the android sdk and java alone isn't enough to understand e.g. what the BD class is. Or did you mean DB there? From my raw java-viewpoint the error is obvious. A `List<Book>` instance and a context needs to be passed to the constructor in `recyclerAdapter = new BookAdapter();` - Pass an emtpy List of Books and `ListBooks.this` as context like below. Just a guess without knowing android and possible side-effects.

Comment: @Bolacer ListBook is not an instance of Context. I would recommend you study basic Java before going into more advanced applications

Comment: Could you transcribe your comments into responses? it would be simpler for me to understand.